# How to use a single form button for multiple user controls

Tags: c#, windows, windows-forms-designer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnBnT.jpg)

I want to create these buttons click event on user controls

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a panel in your main form and generate a button event that adds that user control to that panel, you can achieve this by using the following command `yourpanel.Controls.Add(usercontrolobject);`.
Please note that you should instantiate your user control first a.k.a create a new object of your user control by using the following line of code`usercontrol usercontrolobject = new usercontrol();`

Best Regards.